# div blinking on using jquery .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logo_").hide();
    $("#logo_learn").hide();
})

function sl() {
    $("#logo_learn").slideToggle(500);
    $("#logo_").fadeIn();
}

function hl() {
    $("#logo_learn").slideToggle(500);
    $("#logo_").fadeOut();
}
</script>
<img id="logo_learn" src="img/logo_learn.png"></img>
<img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" onmouseover="sl()" onmouseout="hl()" ></img>
<img id="logo_" src="img/logo_.png" ></img>
</html>
```

I have this html such that on hovering on `logo.png`, `logo_` and `logo_learn` are shown but when i run this on hovering on `logo.png`, `logo_` $ `logo_learn` blinks.pls post a simple answer.

Comment: Please recreate your problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, remember ```<img />``` are self-closing tags. No need to use ```</img>```

Comment: No not use inline event handlers. Bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Use onmouseenter and .stop() like this

**HTML**

```
<img id="logo_learn" src="img/logo_learn.png"></img>
<img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" onmouseenter="sl()" onmouseleave="hl()" ></img>
<img id="logo_" src="img/logo_.png" ></img>
```

**jQuery**

```
  function sl() {
      $("#logo_learn").stop().slideToggle(500);
      $("#logo_").stop().fadeIn();
  }

  function hl() {
      $("#logo_learn").stop().slideToggle(500);
      $("#logo_").stop().fadeOut();
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/sQ7pC/1/)

**Update**

What @epascarello said, dont use inline event handlers, use `.on()` like this code below

```
$('#logo').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $("#logo_learn").stop().slideToggle(500);
    $("#logo_").stop().fadeIn();
});
$('#logo').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $("#logo_learn").stop().slideToggle(500);
    $("#logo_").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: use some sample images so we can see what is going on

Comment: added some images @Kazzkiq

Comment: Sir, your answer worked but only when i use this css:       `@keyframes a{
from{width:0.1px;height:0.1px;margin-left:370px;margin-top:90px;posotion:absolute;}
to{width:700px;height:500px;}
}
#logo{
animation:a 1s;
width:700px;
height:500px;
margin-left:370px;
margin-top:90px;
}
#logo_,
#logo_learn{
width:700px;
height:500px;
margin-left:370px;
top:90px;z-index:200;
}`                                                                   but according to my site i've to make `position:absolute` for `#logo_` & `#logo_learn`, when i do this the code doesn't work.